# Java 8, collect method, creating a new arraylist and mutation

Tags: java, thread-safety, java-8, java-stream

I just want to clarify something regarding the code below:

```
public static void ageOverTen(final List<Human> man) {
    final List<Human> byAge = man.stream()
            .filter(age -> age.getAge() > 10)
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);

    System.out.println("People over 10 years: " + byAge);
}
```

In the Java world we all know `ArrayList` is not thread safe and it's mutable, so when you create a stream and use a `collect()` method, and in it we create an `ArrayList`. How does the library affect `ArrayList` thread safety and mutation, to make it comply with functional programming concept of immutability?

Comment: In particular, in the linked answer: "*This also applies to any of your own non-concurrent collectors that you might implement. They can be used safely with parallel streams, provided your collectors don't interfere with the stream source, are side-effect free, order independent, etc.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `collect()` is designed to work even in parallel, even with non-thread-safe mutable data structures -- provided you follow the rules.  These rules include *non-interference* -- that the behavioral parameters passed to the stream methods (lambdas) do not modify the source of the stream during the operation, and for most operations, *statelessness* -- that the lambdas do not access state that might change during the computation.